# Ruby on Rails exclude group elements in route constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, constraints

I was wondering, how to define constraints regex for my route, that would match only if it excludes every single element of the group.

For instance, I would like to do so:

```
get "list/:action", :constraints => {:action => [NONE OF THE FOLLOWING: (new, edit, delete, update)}
```

I know if we want it to match ANY of the elements of the list, we would have defined so:

`get "list/:action", :constraints => {:action => /(new|edit|delete|update)/},` but I don't know, how to make it work as described above.

I have tried using `^` and `!` signs before the group, but no luck so far - there has to be another notation for that one, I think.

How would I exclude these elements ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following. It'll exclude the actions from the route.

```
class ExcludeActions
  def matches?
    ["new", "edit", "delete", "update"].exclude? params[:action]
  end
end

get "list/:id", :constraints => ExcludeActions.new
```

This will exclude the `new`, `edit`, `delete` and `update` actions from routes for `list`

Comment: No, I cannot use resources directive. I need to use constraints ONLY.

Comment: The class should be written in a separate model named `exclude_actions.rb`